# Error cropped Video openCV

Tags: python, opencv

Estou tendo esse erro quando uso o corte de uma região em um vídeo.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('t8.mp4')

x=0 
y=0
w=650
h=750

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    crop_frame = frame[y: y+h, x: x+w]

    # Just to see the video in real time          
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('croped',crop_frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release() cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
crop frame = frame[y: y+h, x: x+w] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: O erro é este mesmo. Verifique o valor da variável `frame` ela possui o valor `None` (null).

Comment: @Danizavtz obrigada, consegui achar uma solução :)

Comment: Editei sua pergunta para remover mensagens de cumprimentos e seguir as diretrizes da comunidade, [saiba o motivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema:

```
import cv2  
filename = "\\..."
Image= cv2.VideoCapture(filename)

x=0 
y=0 
w=650 
h=750

success, frame = Image.read()

while success :
    success, frame = Image.read()
        
    if success:
        cropeedIMAGE = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.imshow('finger', cropeedIMAGE)
        
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```